# "File is not a valid JSHint library" when trying to use the latest version of jshint with eclipse plugin (Titanium)

Tags: eclipse-plugin, titanium, jshint

On a Mac OS X version 10.7.5 I'm running Appcelerator's Titatium (the latest version at the time of writing this, 3.1) and the jshint-eclipse plugin (http://github.eclipsesource.com/jshint-eclipse/) (the latest version at the time of writing this, 0.9.6). The plugin is running it's "built in" version 1.1.0 of jshint just fine.

I'd like to run the latest version of jshint, which as of the time of writing this is 2.1.1. The plugin's UI has a method to run whatever version of jshint you want: see `Titanium Studio > Preferences > JSHint`. I've used that successfully in the past. But now when I point it to the 2.1.1 versions of jshint.js I've downloaded, the JSHint preference dialog gives the error "File is not a valid JSHint library". So currently I can only run the built-in version.

The jshint.js downloads I've tried are from http://jshint.com/install/. I've tried both the "Node (with NPM)" and "Browser bundle" versions without success.

Is there a way to get the jshint-eclipse plugin version 0.9.6 to run JSHint version 2.1.1, or do I just have to wait for the plugin to be updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has been discussed in [issue 43](https://github.com/eclipsesource/jshint-eclipse/issues/43). It will be fixed in the next jshint-eclipse update. Unfortunately I don't have much time before the annual Eclipse release, but I hope to publish this update next week. In the meantime, you can use the workaround described in this [comment](https://github.com/eclipsesource/jshint-eclipse/issues/43#issuecomment-17284945) (add the following line to the top of `jshint.js`).

```
var window = {};
```

Comment: Your linked comment says the `#!/usr/bin/env rhino` line doesn't work on eclipse, so one only needs to add the `var window = {};` line to the top of the `jshint.js` to get it to work. I've submitted an edit reflecting that, but I'm adding this comment so the correct info is available before the edit is peer reviewed.